# AJAX error al mandar datos con archivos

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, sql-server

Hola estoy tratando de subir un archivo de **exel** a una base de datos /**SQL SERVER 2008** a través de **AJAX**. Pero tengo un problema con el archivo cuando mando los datos ... en este momento no he consegido montar el archivo en el query para ejecutarlo, al contrario el error que manda ajax es el del archivo, mismo no puedo enviar. Agradecería mucho su ayuda :)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo ningún error en consola o el en el explorador más que este, supongo que quiza debo tratar el archivo o algo para poder subirlo.

```html
<form id="uploadForm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class=row "">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Nombre</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="NombreDeProyecto" id="name" />
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Formato</td>
              <td>
                <label>Formato: </label> <input type="file" id="format" />
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Wiw</td>
              <td>
                <p>
                  @Session["Wiw"]
                  <input type="text" class="hidden" id="wiw" value="@Session[" WiW "]" />
                </p>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="button" onclick="tryx()" name="name" value="trymeplz" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>



<script>
  function tryx() {
    var form = new FormData($("#uploadForm")[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("KyoTest", "Home")',
      method: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: form,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(result) {
        alert("at least Ajax looks fine" + response);
      },
      error: function(er) {
        alert("something got wrong" + er);
      }
    });

  }
</script>
```

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KyoTest(testsoru form) {

  string constr = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";



  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
    string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru([Name],[Wiw],[Formato],[Size],[FName],[Type])" +
      " VALUES(@Name,@wiw,@format,@Size,@FName,@Type)";

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)) {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", form.name);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wiw", form.wiw);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@format", form.formato);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", DBNull.Value);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", DBNull.Value);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DBNull.Value);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
    }

  }


  return View(form);
}
//
```

Comment: Prueba a ponerle esto a a tu form: `<form id="uploadForm"   enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`. Y verifica que la URL `url: '@Url.Action("KyoTest", "Home")'`  es correcta.

Comment: No padre @A.Cedano lamento que ese no fuese la solución, obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: Ummm necesitas hacer un append, usando el input donde recoges el archivo. Ejemplo: `var form = document.getElementById("uploadForm");    
form.append( 'file', input.files[0] );`.  Revisa la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData). No quites esto: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, la doc así lo indica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitarás modificar tu script de envío ligeramente, haciendo append de los archivos que haya recogidos en tu formulario.

En SO hay [una respuesta muy interesante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/5587982), que recorre todo el formulario, por si hubiera varios archivos en él y quisieras enviarlos todos.

Esta parte se puede modificar, indicando un sólo file en específico si así se deseara.

```
<script>
  function tryx() {
      var form = new FormData();
      $.each($('#uploadForm')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        form.append('file-'+i, file); //Aquí se agrega un identificador a cada file, no sé si sea útil en tu caso
      });
     console.log(form);

    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("KyoTest", "Home")',
      method: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: form,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(result) {
        alert("at least Ajax looks fine" + response);
      },
      error: function(er) {
        console.log(er);
        alert("something got wrong" + er);
      }
    });

  }
</script>
```

---

**Notas:**

- Revisa la información en la consola, puede que el for se esté creando bien
- Verifica que la URL es correcta, la petición podría fallar a causa de una URL no encontrada
- Verifica que la petición Ajax se maneja bien en el servidor, que el eventual archivo que la recibe no tenga errores.