# Subir imagen BLOB de html sin form a ajax despues a php y grabar en bd

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap, imagen, blob

Tengo la base de datos con image como longblob.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En html lo tengo de esta forma usando bootstrap5:

```html
<div class="col-md-3 position-relative" title="Fotografia">
 <figure class="figure">

  <figcaption class="figure-caption">

<label for="image" id="contenedor_img">
<img id="img" class="image" src="noimagen.png">
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded form-control form-control-sm" aria-label="file example" required accept="image/*" onchange="mostrar()" style="display:none;"/>
</label>

  </figcaption>
</figure>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Ingresa una foto</div>
    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
      Ingresa una foto.
    </div>
  </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn_salvar" onclick="salvar();">Salvar</button>
```

En un archivo separado de funciones.js tengo el ajax:

```html
    function salvar(){
            var id_nombre = $("#id_nombre").val();            
            var id_genero = $('input[name="radio-stacked"]:checked').val();
            var id_estado_civil  = $("#id_estado_civil").val();
            var id_sucursal  = $("#id_sucursal").val();
            var id_area  = $("#id_area").val();
            var id_puesto  = $("#id_puesto").val();
            var id_fecha_nacimiento  = $("#id_fecha_nacimiento").val();
            var edad  = $("#edad").val();
            var id_talla  = $("#id_talla").val();
            var calzado  = $("#calzado").val();
            var fechainicio  = $("#fechainicio").val();
            var id_tipo_sangre  = $("#id_tipo_sangre").val();
            var id_curp  = $("#id_curp").val();
            var id_rfc  = $("#id_rfc").val();
            var telefono  = $("#telefono").val();
            var correo  = $("#correo").val();
            var direccion  = $("#direccion").val();
            var notas  = $("#notas").val();

              var image = document.getElementById('image');

        $.ajax({
            url: "salvar.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
                id_nombre: id_nombre,
                id_genero: id_genero,
                id_estado_civil: id_estado_civil,
                id_sucursal: id_sucursal,
                id_area: id_area,
                id_puesto: id_puesto,
                id_fecha_nacimiento: id_fecha_nacimiento,
                edad: edad,
                id_talla: id_talla,
                calzado: calzado,
                fechainicio: fechainicio,
                id_tipo_sangre: id_tipo_sangre,
                id_curp: id_curp,
                id_rfc: id_rfc,
                telefono: telefono,
                correo: correo,
                direccion: direccion,
                notas: notas,
                
                  image: image
  
                 },            
            success: function(respuesta_actualiza) {            
                alert("Registrado");                
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
            }
          });
    }
```

En el archivo salvar.php tengo el codigo siguiente:

```html
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=backend', 'root', '');

            $id_nombre               = $_POST['id_nombre'];
            $id_genero           = $_POST['id_genero'];
            $id_estado_civil     = $_POST['id_estado_civil'];
            $id_sucursal         = $_POST['id_sucursal'];
            $id_area             = $_POST['id_area'];
            $id_puesto           = $_POST['id_puesto'];
            $id_fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['id_fecha_nacimiento'];
            $edad                = $_POST['edad'];
            $id_talla            = $_POST['id_talla'];
            $calzado             = $_POST['calzado'];
            $fechainicio         = $_POST['fechainicio'];
            $id_tipo_sangre      = $_POST['id_tipo_sangre'];
            $id_curp             = $_POST['id_curp'];
            $id_rfc              = $_POST['id_rfc'];
            $telefono            = $_POST['telefono'];
            $correo              = $_POST['correo'];
            $direccion           = $_POST['direccion'];
            $notas               = $_POST['notas'];
            
              $image               = $_POST['image'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO personal ( 
    nombre,
    id_genero,
    id_estado_civil,
    id_sucursal,
    id_area,
    id_puesto,
    fecha_nacimiento,
    edad,
    id_talla,
    calzado,
    fechainicio,
    id_tipo_sangre,
    curp,
    rfc,
    telefono,
    correo,
    direccion,
    notas,
  
            image

    ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ? )";
    $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([ 
        $id_nombre,
        $id_genero,
        $id_estado_civil,
        $id_sucursal,
        $id_area,
        $id_puesto,
        $id_fecha_nacimiento,
        $edad,
        $id_talla,
        $calzado,
        $fechainicio,
        $id_tipo_sangre,
        $id_curp,
        $id_rfc,
        $telefono,
        $correo,
        $direccion,
        $notas,
    
          $image

         ]);

?>
```

Pero al final no logro guardar la imagen blob en la base de datos.
Solo requiero como pasar correctamente del input file a ajax y de ahi a php y salvarlo en la base de datos.
Pero no quiero usar el form por el momento me causa mas problemas.

Soy nuevo en este tipo de programación.

Si alguien puede asesorarme se lo agradecere.

Comment: Con el formulario es más simple, pero bueno. Para enviar archivos tienes que: 1. indicar que los datos son multipart (esto es más simple declarándolo en el enctype del formulario), si no tendrás que indicarlo en forma de encabezados en tu petición Ajax; 2. En el parámetro `data`  de Ajax tienes que enviar un objeto `FormData` ; 3. En el servidor, los archivos (entre ellos la imagen) no se encontrarían en el `$_POST`, si no en `$_FILES` (eso es lo que significa multipart), cuando van adjuntos, los datos van en varias partes, digamos, por un lado los datos simples y por otro los archivos.

Comment: 1.- <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" id="enviarformulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>

Comment: 2 & 3.- ¡No se como hacerlo!. Disculpa soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Este tema ha sido tratado ya en varias preguntas/respuestas aquí, aunque los escenarios no sean exactamente los mismos. Te dejo aquí algunas: [Resp. 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/426611/29967), también,  [Resp. 2, con indicaciones sobre manejo en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158711/29967), y además, [Resp. 3  explica cómo adjuntar varios archivos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116527/29967). Creo que revisando esos ejemplos y otros podrás formarte una idea y salir adelante y si te quedas bloqueado en algo puedes preguntar aquí. Te refiero a esas respuestas como punto de partida.

Comment: Por ejemplo, una de las ventajas de usar `FormData` es que, si lanzas la petición Ajax desde un evento submit del formulario y necesitas enviar todos los datos del formulario, haciendo esto los estarías recogiendo todos: `var formData = new FormData(this);` y luego pasarías la variable `formData` en el parámetro `data` de la petición Ajax ([eso se explica en la Resp. 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/426611/29967)) . En el primer bloque de código de esa respuesta hay un ejemplo completo sobre esa forma de trabajar con `FormData`.

Comment: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=backend', 'root', ''); $nombre = $_POST['nom']; $pic = $_FILES['img']; $query = "INSERT INTO personal (nombre, image) VALUES ( '$nombre', '$pic' )"; $db->query($query);

Comment: Me sale este error: Notice: Array to string conversion in salvar.php on line 95, pero me guarda en la tabla un archivo de [BLOB - 5 B] en el campo blob

Comment: Cuando tengas problemas en el código PHP usa `var_dump` para depurar tus variables. En este caso, pon un `var_dump($_POST);` y también un `var_dump($_FILES);` así podrás revisar si los datos están llegando y cómo están organizados. Generalmente los datos de `$_FILES` vienen en un arreglo de dos dimensiones.

Comment: Ahora me salio esto y no registro los valores solo creo un registro vacio: array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'Alexander.jpg' (length=13)
  'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\php8354.tmp' (length=25)
  'error' => int 0
  'size' => int 26664

Comment: Tendrías que crear un BLOB con el archivo, con algo así más o menos: ` $image = file_get_contents($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]);` y luego intenta insertar `$image` donde iría el BLOB. Es mucho más seguro indicar el tipo de dato, usando `bindParam()`, no estoy seguro de que funcione pasándolo en el `execute()`.

Comment: Encontre una solución como la publico?

Comment: Puedes escribirlo como respuesta a tu propia pregunta, es válido.

Comment: Te agradezco tu tiempo, conocimiento y ayuda. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function salvar(event) {
  //event.preventDefault();    
  /*Se crea el objeto vacío*/
  var formData = new FormData();

  var nombre = document.getElementById('id_nombre').value;
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
  //    var id_genero = document.getElementByname('radio-stacked').value;
  var id_estado_civil = document.getElementById('id_estado_civil').value;
  var id_sucursal = document.getElementById('id_sucursal').value;
  var id_area = document.getElementById('id_area').value;
  var id_puesto = document.getElementById('id_puesto').value;
  var id_fecha_nacimiento = document.getElementById('id_fecha_nacimiento').value;
  var edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
  var id_talla = document.getElementById('id_talla').value;
  var calzado = document.getElementById('calzado').value;
  var fechainicio = document.getElementById('fechainicio').value;
  var id_tipo_sangre = document.getElementById('id_tipo_sangre').value;
  var id_curp = document.getElementById('id_curp').value;
  var id_rfc = document.getElementById('id_rfc').value;
  var telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
  var correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
  var direccion = document.getElementById('direccion').value;
  var notas = document.getElementById('notas').value;
  /* ***************************************************************** */

  /*OJO: No se usa value para los input file*/
  var photo = document.getElementById('image').files[0];

  /*Agregamos los datos por separado*/
  formData.append('nombre', nombre);
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
  //    formData.append('radio-stacked',genero);
  formData.append('id_estado_civil', id_estado_civil);
  formData.append('id_sucursal', id_sucursal);
  formData.append('id_area', id_area);
  formData.append('id_puesto', id_puesto);
  formData.append('id_fecha_nacimiento', id_fecha_nacimiento);
  formData.append('edad', edad);
  formData.append('id_talla', id_talla);
  formData.append('calzado', calzado);
  formData.append('fechainicio', fechainicio);
  formData.append('id_tipo_sangre', id_tipo_sangre);
  formData.append('id_curp', id_curp);
  formData.append('id_rfc', id_rfc);
  formData.append('telefono', telefono);
  formData.append('correo', correo);
  formData.append('direccion', direccion);
  formData.append('notas', notas);
  /* ***************************************************************** */

  formData.append('img', photo);

  $.ajax({
      url: 'salvar.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: "html"

    })
    .done(function(res) {
      $('#respuesta').html(res)
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log(nombre);
    });

};
```

```html
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=backend', 'root', '');

        $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
//      $id_genero           = $_POST['id_genero'];
        $id_estado_civil     = $_POST['id_estado_civil'];
        $id_sucursal         = $_POST['id_sucursal'];
        $id_area             = $_POST['id_area'];
        $id_puesto           = $_POST['id_puesto'];
        $id_fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['id_fecha_nacimiento'];
        $edad                = $_POST['edad'];
        $id_talla            = $_POST['id_talla'];
        $calzado             = $_POST['calzado'];
        $fechainicio         = $_POST['fechainicio'];
        $id_tipo_sangre      = $_POST['id_tipo_sangre'];
        $id_curp             = $_POST['id_curp'];
        $id_rfc              = $_POST['id_rfc'];
        $telefono            = $_POST['telefono'];
        $correo              = $_POST['correo'];
        $direccion           = $_POST['direccion'];
        $notas               = $_POST['notas'];
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
        $name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $type = $_FILES['img']['type'];
        $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO personal (
        nombre,
        id_estado_civil,
        id_sucursal,
        id_area,
        id_puesto,
        fecha_nacimiento,
        edad,
        id_talla,
        calzado,
        fechainicio,
        id_tipo_sangre,
        curp,
        rfc,
        telefono,
        correo,
        direccion,
        notas,
        image
    )
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $stmt->bindParam(1,$nombre);
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$id_estado_civil);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$id_sucursal);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$id_area);
    $stmt->bindParam(5,$id_puesto);
    $stmt->bindParam(6,$id_fecha_nacimiento);
    $stmt->bindParam(7,$edad);
    $stmt->bindParam(8,$id_talla);
    $stmt->bindParam(9,$calzado);
    $stmt->bindParam(10,$fechainicio);
    $stmt->bindParam(11,$id_tipo_sangre);
    $stmt->bindParam(12,$id_curp);
    $stmt->bindParam(13,$id_rfc);
    $stmt->bindParam(14,$telefono);
    $stmt->bindParam(15,$correo);
    $stmt->bindParam(16,$direccion);
    $stmt->bindParam(17,$notas);
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
    $stmt->bindParam(18,$data);
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```